# Cancel REST service when request is cancelled

Tags: java, rest

I have a snippet from angular UI that will call myService.getNames() when user types in a letter in the field.  The switchMap will cancel the previous request whenever the user types in another letter in the field.

```
.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    switchMap(value => this.myService.getNames(value))
)
```

This service will call the REST endpoint `http://localhost:8080/listing?value=<value_sent_from_client>`.  The query for retrieving the list of names takes some time to complete.  If the user edited the field 3 times, there will be 2 cancelled requests and 1 on-going request.

On the server side, how do you cancel the 2 previously running queries? Or will they get cancelled automatically?

Comment: I have the ame problem. I can cancel the requests within the angular front end, but I have put some indicators at my node server and it seems that the "cancelled" requests are not cancelled at all. Only the UI does not expect any response from their side. Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cancel request on server side. The solution might be in more sophisticated algorithm, like:

- each request are putting into queue and return immediately not waiting for processing to be finished (storing in DB, etc.)
- queue replace previous items if new items are present from same user
- client subscribes to updates from server via web-sockets

Or any other approach.